# How to call a function and then navigate to a route when click on a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code.

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-secondary" onClick={this.addToCart.bind(
    this,
    this.state.itemDetails.product.images[0].path,
    this.state.itemDetails.name,
    this.state.itemDetails.id,
    this.state.itemDetails.unitPrice,
    this.state.quantity
)} >
    <Link to="/proceedToCheckout">
    Buy Now
    </Link>
</button>
```

Here I want to call the event onClick and with that I want to direct page to the link "/proceedToCheckout" when I click on the button. I want to do both of this with a single button click. 
In the above code, when I click on the button area it calls the addToCart function. But route is not working. If I click on the word "Buy Now" (the link) then it directs to the route. But I want to do is with a single button click I need to call the function "addToCart" and then to direct to the route "/proceedToCheckout"

Comment: `this.props.history.push('/proceedToCheckout')` add this into your click function and remove the link component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, I have done some changes:

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-secondary" onClick={this.addToCart.bind(
this,
this.state.itemDetails.product.images[0].path,
this.state.itemDetails.name,
this.state.itemDetails.id,
this.state.itemDetails.unitPrice,
this.state.quantity )} >

Buy Now </button>
```

And In the 'addToCart' function, I have added the routing which you want to achieve

```
addToCart= () => {
   .... // what you want to achieve in this function
   ....
   this.props.history.push('/proceedToCheckout');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return <Redirect to='/proceedToCheckout'/>;
```

Instead of

```
<Link to="/proceedToCheckout">Buy Now</Link>
```

Please import Redirect from your router library.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/proceedToCheckout')}>Buy Now</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.